# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read a list of category name from database into an array list; I am then binding the list into dropdown box.  I am getting this error and i am not sure how to resolve it.  Please help.  thanks

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem
```

the code is failing at this line:

```
foreach (ListItem item in arr)
```

here is what i have in code behind

```
  private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl)
        {
            ArrayList arr = GetDummyData();
            foreach (ListItem item in arr)
            {
                ddl.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

  private ArrayList GetDummyData()
        {              
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString.ToString();
                 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct ct_name from myTable", con);
            SqlDataReader objDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objDR != null)
                while (objDR.Read())
                {
                    //fill arraylist
                    arr.Add(objDR["ct_name"]);
                }
            con.Close();
            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: `foreach (string item in arr)` use this, because your `ArrayList` contains `string`s no `ListItem`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayList contains Strings. Your loop tries to iterate over them as `ListItems`, which they aren't, thus bits fly everywhere. Change your iteration variable type to 'string'

```
foreach (string item in arr)
```

BTW: ArrayLists are almost certainly less preferable in more contemporary code than `List<String>` types. ArrayLists are kind of a holdover from the pre-generics era.

Comment: Great! Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your ArrayList contains strings, then you're trying to iterate over it as if it has ListItem's in it. You need to change your foreach to:

```
foreach (string item in arr)
{
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
}
```